# determining if textarea has text or not using jQuery

Tags: jquery, textarea

I would like my forms submit button to fadeIn when the textarea box has text in it and fadeOut when it does not. Additionally, I've clickable text that dynamically fills the textarea. I have also given the option of simply typing a message in the textarea.

I have come across several solutions on here and on other forums but none seem to be the solution to my problem.

In the code below 'Attempted Solution' I am going through each textarea/ message box using '$.each', I then check to see if it '.is' one of the textarea / message boxes in messageListArray. If it is one of those textarea / message boxes I'm attempting to check value '.val()' , length '.length', and remove any white space '.trim' to determine if the textarea has any text. If the textarea does have text i want the submit button to '.fadeIn('slow') otherwise if it does not I want the submit button to '.fadeOut('slow').

Update Code: I updated the code using comparison operate "===" but it is still not working.

```
const  signupWordList = $('#signup-clickWordList li'),
        featuresWordList = $('#features-clickWordList li'),
        dislikeWordList = $('#dislike-clickWordList li'),
        signupMessage = $('#signup-txtMessage'),
        featuresMessage = $('#features-txtMessage'),
        dislikeMessage = $('#dislike-txtMessage'),
        hidden_btn = $('.temp-hide-btn'),
        wordListArray = [signupWordList, featuresWordList, dislikeWordList],
        messageListArray = [signupMessage, featuresMessage, dislikeMessage];

     $.each(messageListArray, function(index, value) {
            if(value === signupMessage) {
                console.log($(this).val().trim().length <= 0);
                if($(this).val().trim().length <= 0) {
                    hidden_btn.fadeOut('slow');
                } else {
                    hidden_btn.fadeIn("slow");
                }
            } else if(value === featuresMessage) {
                if($(this).val().trim().length <= 0) {
                    hidden_btn.fadeIn('slow');
                } else {
                    hidden_btn.fadeOut("slow");
                }
            } else if(value === dislikeMessage) {
                if($(this).val().trim().length <= 0) {
                    hidden_btn.fadeOut('slow');
                } else {
                    hidden_btn.fadeIn("slow");
                }
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
        <section id="freeForm-questions">
            <div class="height">

                <div class="image__wrapper">
                    <img class="image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/xUOxf5Ry3MACleimPu/giphy.gif"
                         alt="new feature gif">
                </div>

                <h3 class="message-box-title">Message Box</h3>

                <div class="message-box-container">
                    <div class="form">
                        <div class="message">
                            <label for="features-txtMessage"></label>
                            <textarea id="features-txtMessage" name="features-txtMessage"
                                      class="txtDropTarget ui-droppable"
                                      placeholder="enter your ideas or click an insert feature"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clickable-questions">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>Click to insert:</legend>

                                <ul id="features-clickWordList">
                                    <li id="click1"></li>
                                    <li id="click2"></li>
                                    <li id="click3"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn yellow temp-hide-btn scrollTo" data-scrollTo="timePref-questions" value="Submit">
                </div><!--message-box-container-->
            </div>
        </section>

<section id="features-questions">
            <div class="height">
                              <div class="image__wrapper">
                    <img class="image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/fseQbeRriqgzTHqbXL/giphy.gif"
                         alt="new feature gif">
                </div>

                <h3 class="message-box-title">Message Box</h3>

                <div class="message-box-container">
                    <div class="form">
                        <div class="message">
                            <label for="signup-txtMessage"></label>
                            <textarea id="signup-txtMessage" name="signup-txtMessage" class="txtDropTarget ui-droppable"
                                      placeholder="Please select one of the click to insert options that represent how you feel the most or begin typing your own comments / suggestions here."></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clickable-questions">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>Click to insert:</legend>

                                <ul id="signup-clickWordList">
                                    <li id="click4"></li>
                                    <li id="click5"></li>
                                    <li id="click6"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn yellow temp-hide-btn" value="Submit">
                </div><!--message-box-container-->
            </div>
        </section>

<section id="dislike-questions">
            <div class="height">
                <div class="image__wrapper">
                    <img class="image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/4cuyucPeVWbNS/giphy.gif"
                         alt="dislike it gif">
                </div>

                <h3 class="message-box-title">Message Box</h3>

                <div class="message-box-container">
                    <div class="form">
                        <div class="message">
                            <label for="dislike-txtMessage"></label>
                            <textarea id="dislike-txtMessage" name="dislike-txtMessage"
                                      class="txtDropTarget ui-droppable"
                                      placeholder="Please select one of the click to insert options that represent how you feel the most or begin typing your own comments / suggestions here."></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clickable-questions">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>Click to insert:</legend>

                                <ul id="dislike-clickWordList">
                                    <li id="click7"></li>
                                    <li id="click8"></li>
                                    <li id="click9"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn yellow temp-hide-btn scrollTo" data-scrollTo="contentPref-questions_no"
                           value="Submit">
                </div><!--message-box-container-->
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Please, don't add your entire code in the question, add jsut the sufficient to explain your problem. read about [mcve]

Comment: When you're checking vs the Array, how are you gathering that array? Is there a certain class you are looking for to add it in the array?

Comment: @CalvinNunes I included the entire block of code that relates to the component. But I also included Attempted Solution to show what I've tried in hopes of figuring out what i was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would look to remove the duplication.

You could rewrite that specific `each` function like this:

```
// determines if textarea has text if it doesn't hide submit button
    $.each(messageListArray, function(index, value) {
        if(value === signupMessage || value === dislikeMessage) {
            if($(this).val().trim().length <= 0) {
                hidden_btn.fadeOut('slow');
            } else {
                hidden_btn.fadeIn("slow");
            }
        } else if(value === featuresMessage) {
            if($(this).val().trim().length <= 0) {
                hidden_btn.fadeIn('slow');
            } else {
                hidden_btn.fadeOut("slow");
            }
    });
```

What is `messageListArray`?

Comment: Thanks. messageListArray is a a collection of the textareas in the DOM

Comment: this didn't work for me unfortunately. I will update my code with what i have but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I found a solution to the problem using your suggestions and examples I found through searching on google.

```
// determines if textarea has text if it doesn't hide submit button
    $.each(messageListArray, function (index, value) {
        value.bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
            if (value.is(signupMessage)) {
                const signUpTrim = $.trim($(this).val());
                if (signUpTrim !== "") {
                    hidden_btn.fadeIn('slow');
                } else if (signUpTrim === ""){
                    hidden_btn.fadeOut('slow');
                }
            } else if (value.is(featuresMessage)) {
                const featuresTrim = $.trim($(this).val());
                if(featuresTrim !== "") {
                    hidden_btn.fadeIn('slow');
                } else if (featuresTrim === ""){
                    hidden_btn.fadeOut('slow');
                }
            } else if (value.is(dislikeMessage)) {
                const dislikeTrim = $.trim($(this).val());
                if(dislikeTrim !== "") {
                    hidden_btn.fadeIn('slow');
                } else if (dislikeTrim === ""){
                    hidden_btn.fadeOut('slow');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```